# Почему возникает ошибка при подключении

Tags: python, wordpress

Я пытаюсь с помощью python написать скрипт для авто-постинга на Wordpress. Но при запуске я получаю ошибку - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хотя я должен получить Response [201]
код:

```
import requests
import json
import base64

url = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2'
user = 'user'
password = 'password'

creds = user + ':' + password
token = base64.b64encode(creds.encode())

header = {'Autohrization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')}

post = {
    'date': '2022-08-23T18:27:00',
    'title': 'Please',
    'content': 'Please work i realy want',
    'status': 'publish'
}

r = requests.post(url + '/posts', headers = header, json=post)
print(r)
```

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что у вас на порту 80 никто не принимает подключения

Comment: И до кучи - выкинь эту кривую дыру и используй https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/ и пароли приложений https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/rest/basic/authentication/application-passwords.